# Как посчитать сколько раз сработал цикл?

Tags: python

Есть лотерея, которая показывает "4 случайные победные комбинации". Нужно с помощью цикла while сравнить эти комбинации со своим победным билетом (например 1111) и сколько раз сработал цикл, пока мы к этому не пришли. Начало вот такое, потом когда пишу While и "скажем в упор" (while == или !=)сравниваю с 1111, на мой взгляд идет бесконечный цикл и делаю что-то не так, счет идет вперед без остановки(

```
from random import choice

result = []
numbers = [0, 1, 'A', 2, 3, 'B', 4, 5, 'C', 6, 7, 'D', 8, 9, 10]

for f in range(4):
    result.append(choice(numbers))

print(*result, sep='')
```

Comment: ну так-то вариантов (количество сочетаний) для вашего случая может быть 1365. может, много это для вашего кода - каждый раз выбирать и сравнивать

Comment: для начала уменьшите список `numbers` до 2,3 элементов, чтобы проверить, бесконечный цикл или нет. а так вводите счетчик и увеличивайте его внутри цикла. после выхода из цикла читайте его значение.